# React Redux Typescript call dispatch action from function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, react-typescript

I am making an API call, after which I want to update the store with {apiExecuted: true} by calling the ACTION_API_EXECUTED action.

What is the best way to achieve this by using dispatch?

Comment: I mean there are ways to hack around this with async redux libs, like importing the store object and accessing its dispatch function. But in reality you shouldn't be doing it that way. Best to use something like `redux-thunk` to make an action that does this async task and has access to dispatch by default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do this asynchronously in the action with the use of `thunk`, `saga` or an `epic`, depending upon the configuration of your project.
Based on the API response, you can then dispatch another action call to update the state.